# Compare list with an exact or scrambled match of a long text

Tags: python

I have the following list I want to iterate over it and find if there's a scramble match with the long string `aapxjdnrbtvldptfzbbdbbzxtndrvjblnzjfpvhdhhpxjdnrbt` and return the number of matches. **The below example should return 4**

A scramble string basically starts and ends with the same letter, the rest letters are rearranged.

```
long_string = 'aapxjdnrbtvldptfzbbdbbzxtndrvjblnzjfpvhdhhpxjdnrbt'
my_list = [
    'axpaj', # this is scrambled version of aapxj
    'apxaj', # this is scrambled version of aapxj
    'dnrbt', # this is exact match of dnrbt
    'pjxdn', # this is scrambled version of pxjdn
    'abd',
]

matches = 0
for l in my_list:
    # check for exact match
        if l in long_string:
            matches += 1
    # check for a scramble match
    # ...
# matches = 1. Wrong should be 4.


def is_anagram(str1, str2):
    str1_list = list(str1)
    str1_list.sort()
    str2_list = list(str2)
    str2_list.sort()
    return (str1_list == str2_list)


is_anagram('axpaj' , 'aapxjdnrbtvldptfzbbdbbzxtndrvjblnzjfpvhdhhpxjdnrbt')

['a', 'a', 'j', 'p', 'x']
['a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'd', 'd', 'd', 'd', 'd', ...]
```

Comment: You shouldn't name a list "list" in Python, as "list" is a reserved keyword and it can cause problems later

Comment: This was an interview question my coworker and I asked candidates way back when. You're trying to find anagrams within a substring, so I'd ask how you'd determine if a string is an anagram of other. And then apply that thinking to determining if multiple strings are anagrams of one. Then move onto applying that to trying to find substring anagrams inside a large string.

Comment: @wkl alright, thanks for help I'll search out

Comment: alphabetized versions of two anagrams will match.

Comment: @RufusVS added a method is_anagram, which does what you said. However they don't match

Comment: They have be the same length!  So you have to compare slices of the long string, not the whole thing!

Comment: `is_anagram` can be simplified to one line: `return sorted(str1) == sorted(str2)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This creates sorted match strings for each different word length required.  It builds them on the fly to avoid excess processing.
(Edit: Oops, the previous version assumed one long string in doing the caching.  Thanks for the catch, @BeRT2me!)

```
long_string = 'aapxjdnrbtvldptfzbbdbbzxtndrvjblnzjfpvhdhhpxjdnrbt'
my_list = [
    'axpaj', # this is scrambled version of aapxj
    'apxaj', # this is scrambled version of aapxj
    'dnrbt', # this is exact match of dnrbt
    'pjxdn', # this is scrambled version of pxjdn
    'abd',
]

anagrams = {}  # anagrams contains sorted slices for each word length

def is_anagram(str1,str2):
    lettercount = len(str1)
    cachekey = (str2,lettercount)
    if cachekey not in anagrams:
        # build the list for that letter length
        anagrams[cachekey] = [sorted(str2[x:x+lettercount]) for x in range(len(str2)-lettercount+1)]
    return (sorted(str1) in anagrams[cachekey])


matches = 0
for l in my_list:
    if is_anagram(l,long_string):
        matches += 1

print (f"There are {matches} in my list.")
```

Comment: You will need to be careful with this method to reset `anagrams` any time a new `long_string` is supplied~

Comment: I don' think it's very accurate. If you have in the list `spatra` and in the long text `thisissparta` it's not matching

Comment: @csandreas1  Classic off-by-one error.  Edited to accommodate comments.

Answer (score 0):

I think step 1 of finding a solution is to write code which cuts off the first and last letter of a string.

```
someFunction("abcde") should return "bcd"
```

Next you'd need some way to check if the letters in the string are all the same. I would do this by alphabetising and comparing corresponding elements.

```
alphabetize("khfj") gives "fhjk"

isSame("abc","abc") gives True
```

You'd then need a way of cutting the string into every substring of a specified length, e.g.:

```
thisFunction("abcdef", 2) gives ["ab", "bc", "cd", "de", "ef"]
```

Once you have every possible substring of the length you can check for scramble matches by checking each item in the list against every substring in long_string with the same length

Answer (score 0):

Here's a basic approach – iterate over all substrings of `long_string` with the matching length and check if they are equal to the search item after sorting.

```py
matches = 0

for x in my_list:
    
    # simple case 1: exact match
    if x in long_string:
        matches += 1
        continue
    
    # sort the string - returns a list
    x = sorted(x)
    
    # simple case 2: exact match after sorting
    if ''.join(x) in long_string:
        matches += 1
        continue
    
    window_size = len(x)
    
    for i in range(len(long_string)-window_size):
        
        # sort the substring
        y = sorted(long_string[i:i+window_size])

        # compare - note that both x and y are lists, 
        # but it doesn't make any difference for this purpose
        if x == y:
            matches += 1
            break
```

Note that this won't be very efficient because the substrings are re-sorted for every loop. An easy way to optimize would be to store the sorted substrings in a dictionary that maps substring lengths to sets of sorted substrings (`{4: {'aapx', 'ajpx', 'djpx', ...}}`).

Answer (score 0):

Throw a little Regex at it for an interesting solution:

- Finds str matches that:

  - Start and end the same.
  - Are the same length.
  - Only contain the same inner letters as the sublist.
- Checks that the sorted item matches the sorted substring. And that they don't match unsorted.

```
import re

def is_anagram(str1, str2):
    return sorted(str1) == sorted(str2) and str1 != str2

def get_matches(str1, str2):
    start, middle, end = str1[0], str1[1:-1], str1[-1]
    pattern = fr'{start}[{middle}]{{{len(middle)}}}{end}'
    return re.findall(pattern, str2)

matches = 0
for l in my_list:
    for item in get_matches(l, long_string):
        if is_anagram(item, l):
            matches += 1

print(matches)

# Output:
4
```